# JavaScript synchronise multiple function calls

Tags: javascript

I have a document, which has two `javascript` functions `A();` and `B();`.The functions get called in no particular order, I want to do something upon the last call.

I can accomplish the task by using local variables, but before doing so I'd like to confirm if there's more elegant/robust way for doing that - I might have more than two such functions, which makes local vars solution a complete mess.

Update 1 - More details

I've a few SilverLight plugins on a page, each has

```
<param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded" />
```

I can't go any further than "pluginLoaded" no paramters no nothing.

The plugins get loaded in an absolute random order, upon the overall completion I want to call another function.

Comment: How do they get called? event callbacks? provide some code please so we can better answer the question.

Comment: Pls provide a code sample or demo on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @Rufus not feasible sorry -  I'm using SilverLight plugins.

Comment: Is there any bridge between Silverlight and JavaScript (Something like ExternalInterface in Flash) ?

Comment: Can you change the code to something like `<param name="onLoad" value="My_pluginLoaded" />` then in your own `My_pluginLoaded` manually call `pluginLoaded`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Radoslav Georgiev - there's absolutely none - I'm looking for a JS analog of WaitHandle.WaitAll, is there anything like that in JS?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - good idea I probably can, but I still have to deal with synchrinizing the calls, don't I?

Comment: @Rufus - I want to call something upon completion of A, B, .. Z where A,B..Z are Javascript functions called in a random order. Does it make sense?

Comment: You don't have to synchronize - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do this by redifining the functions:

You now have:

```
function A() { /* do something */ }
function B() { /* do something */ }
function FinalCurtain() { /* do something after A and B have been called*/ }
```

Just do
**EDIT: After requirement "I'd like doA & doB to be called just once each"**

```
function DoA() { /* do something */ }
function DoB() { /* do something */ }
function DoFinalCurtain() { /* do something after A and B have been called*/ }

function A() {
   DoA();
   B=function() {DoB(); FinalCurtain();}
   A=function() {}
}

function B() {
   DoB();
   A=function() {DoA(); FinalCurtain();}
   B=function() {}
}

function FinalCurtain() {
   DoFinalCurtain();
   //Remove next 2 lines if you do NOT want to start the process over once DoFinalCurtain() has beenm called.
   A=function() {DoA();}
   B=function() {DoB();}
}
```

Comment: @Eugen Rieck - Looks interesting but am I guaranteed for FinalCurtain to be called just once? Also both A & B are guaranteed to be called, so I'd like doA & doB to be called just once each.

Comment: ... which is the case for all methods I am aware of. The best-scaling approach is to have a global list of functions called, every relevant "before" function does something like `FunctionsCalled.A=true` and ever "after" function does something like `if(FunctionsCalled.A && FunctionsCalled.B)` but we dropped it because of undebugability.

Comment: This doesn't seem dry and would lead to a very messy codebase with more functions involved.

Comment: @PeterOlson De gustibus non est disputandum! As I mentioned, we tried a couple of things including a List, and we ended up in manually writing the DoXXX functions and generating the XXX functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, but I'm not sure if it's elegant enough.

You need one global variable:

```
functionsCalled = {};
```

one function that `A` and `B` both need to call with `recordCall(arguments.callee)`

```
function recordCall(fn){
  functionsCalled[fn] = 1;
}
```

And finally a function that accepts an array of functions that checks each one to see if they have been called and calls a certain function if they have. You can call it like `haveBeenCalled([A, B], function { ... });`

```
function haveBeenCalled(fns, fn) {
  for(var i = 0; i < fns.length; i++) {
    if(fns[i] !== 1) return;
  }
  return fn();
}
```

Comment: This is what I mentioned in my comment to my answer above - we used it some time, but dropped it because of debugging issues

Comment: I'm curious, why would this be particularly hard to debug?

Comment: First: Our approach was similar, but not identical (look above). Second: the problem was, that following the list (if it grows large) was more error prone than following the (newly defined) functions. Especially if during a long-running AJAX call the list changed, you would see a list, that no longer reflects the state of the AJAX call

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. Could you come up with an example script where the list would be error-prone?

Comment: Not the LIST is error prone, but watching the list (as a human being) is: Say your list has function A NOT called, you start an AJAX call. While this runs, function A is called. Now your AJAX call returns and sees a different list. If you single-step this in the debugger, chances are that the AJAX call will return before A is called

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML to something like this:

```
<param name="onLoad" value="My_firstPluginLoaded" />
...
<param name="onLoad" value="My_secondPluginLoaded" />
...
<param name="onLoad" value="My_thirdPluginLoaded" />
```

Then have such code in your page:

```
var loadedPlugingCount = 0;
var totalPlugins = 3;

function My_firstPluginLoaded() {
    loadedPlugingCount++;
    firstPluginLoaded();
}

function My_secondPluginLoaded() {
    loadedPlugingCount++;
    secondPluginLoaded();
}

function My_thirdPluginLoaded() {
    loadedPlugingCount++;
    thirdPluginLoaded();
}

function CheckAllCompleted() {
    if (loadedPlugingCount === totalPlugins) {
        alert("All done!");
        return true;
    }
    window.setTimeout(CheckAllCompleted, 10);
    return false;
}

CheckAllCompleted();
```

The idea is simple: have your own function, in there increment global counter before invoking the real callback, then check the counter until it reach the desired count.

Comment: Don't Repeat Yourself. It's messy when you have basically identical code repeated like tgis.